# Why can a bundle file be applied even I rename or remove it from the project

Tags: ios

I'm really confused about this tutorial program. I added a bundle file (.xib) for a view controller and use `initWithBundle` to get the file as views. While I change name of the bundle file which as same name as view controller, I suppose view controller could not find the bundle file for I used init method instead of `initWithBundle`. But controller get it in. Then, I removed the bundle file utterly from project into trash, and when I run the project the view in bundle, the file still got into UI. Is there any cache for the emulator or something I missed to change?

Comment: A `.xib` file isn't a bundle.  Have you looked at the contents of the app bundle after being built?

Comment: There is a cache inside Xcode, try clean before running again. Also the constructor for the xib file is initWithNibName

Comment: sorry guys, some incorrect name of the file ^_^ I did run the program as expected for no view of bundle file display in UI finally...Well I still have a question about Xcode. When I build an Android App by Eclipse (ADT) I could whenever remove any resource or view and see result without having to clean cache. Why Xcode or its emulator hold the bundle file even I remove it from project?